# Provide a markdown extension to hide text (anti spoiler)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spoilers, design

Cool it has been implemented.

> I like it

---

Most of my text would not be spoilers but there may be a small part of my question which may mention something that could be a spoiler.

It would be great if I could  hide the text so you need to mouseover or click to see the *spoiler*

I am thinking this could be a feature. The question shouldnt be marked as a spoiler if it isnt and is just mentioning something that could be a spoiler to someone not as far in the game.

This request is in a similar spirit for something similar that was implemented for [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (The pretty-formulas-display extension)

Comment: This has already been suggested (and up-voted) [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-we-behave-with-questions-answers-that-reveal-spoiler/51#51). I personally think it's a great idea, even though it's probably something only useful for very few of the StackExchange sites at the moment.

Comment: One of our responsibilities as moderators is to bring this kind of things to the attention of the SE team. So if a feature like this gets enough support, we'll take the suggestion to them!

Comment: So people should vote here if they want this

Comment: @Oak, math.se got a great extension for formulas and that's only useful to them -- I don't think that it being useful to few sites is a big no-no

Comment: @Juan: A big part of that was because the StackExchange team was implementing an existing solution rather than coming up with something from scratch. See [this meta.so answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57931/area51-se-2-0-site-specific-script-support-such-as-latex-in-beta-phase/58450#58450). If someone could track down a good spoiler marking system and figure out how it could be implemented on gaming.se, and present it in those terms, I think it will be much more likely to get added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A network wide syntax has been added for spoilers.

[Details on the meta.stackoverflow feature request.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text/71396#71396)

Comment: Yay!!!!!!15char

Comment: Actually, it is currently missing documentation at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help And without documentation, users won't find it...

Comment: FWIW, it's now included on the editing-help page.

Answer (score 3):

Please also indicate your support by voting on [the request at meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text) (the mother of all Metas) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-a-spoiler-tag-that-makes-hidden-until-you-click-text/60012#60012).

*Grace Note: The request on Meta has been marked [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)! It looks like this will be implemented sometime in the future!*

Answer (score 3):

[dbr pointed out a workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1223) that we can use in the meantime.

```
                                                                                                                     Rosebud is the sled!
```

Four spaces at the start of a line begins a code block, more spaces push the text past the maximum width of the column.

Not optimal, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

For now the best we can do is use the `spoilers` tag. People who don't want to be spoiled can include it in their ignored tags.

If you see spoilers in a question that isn't tagged spoilers I guess you can flag the post. :)

Comment: or tag it yourself if you can do so.