# Stylize 'spoiler' tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

Along the same lines as the various logo'ed tags over on SF, and the colored tags on the Meta SE sites, it would be nice to see some kind of style applied to the spoiler tag here on G.SE. It could be as simple as a soft/dark red, or black background (with appropriate text color too, of course), or a small icon that properly indicates the meaning of "abandon all hope at being able to complete the game on your own, ye who enter here" to all digital passersby.

Skull and Crossbones icon, maybe? In addition to a black background? :)

Comment: I support this.  I think red should be a prominent colour, as sort of a 'danger warning!'

Comment: who's going to make a userscript for this? ;)

Comment: I imagine the icon is/will be reserved for sponsorships, but even an outline (like on Meta SO) to make it stand out a bit would be pretty nice.

Comment: Seems weird to reserve sponsorships for gaming. I don't know why, it just sounds odd.

Answer (score 3):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)* as we no longer have a [spoiler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) tag anyway. Use Spoiler markdown to denote spoilers instead, e.g:

```
>! spoiler text
```

resulting in:

> spoiler text

<sub>* This should at least stop Community User from re-bumping this question</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> [We no longer need the [spoiler] tag.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/736/provide-a-markdown-extension-to-hide-text-anti-spoiler)

Comment: I disagree. I think noting spoilers in addition to taking precaution to obscure them, are BOTH important.

Comment: How about spoiler in titles?

Comment: @badp A tag hardly protects against a spoiler in a title. If anything, it can reveal what otherwise was not known to be a spoiler (like, for example, how plot relevant a question might be).

Comment: @Grace It does if you ignore the tag...

Comment: @badp Point taken. But if you need it only for ignoring, then a stylized tag is less than necessary, then, aye?

Comment: @badp I believe we try to avoid (or even disallow) spoilers in titles in the firts place.

Answer (score 0):

I support this. I made a similar request on English.SE, in regards to the quote formatting style. Each site has its own style which fits the genre. However, custom styling is difficult to maintain and may not be worth the effort for SE to do.