# Should text with the spoiler markdown appear in question summaries?

Tags: support, spoilers

I noticed that if a question uses the `>!` spoiler markdown within the first 200 characters, then the "hidden" text will still appear in the question summary that is displayed in search results.

For example, [search](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:2498%20%5Bspoiler%5D%20%5Bportal-2%5D) for this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22136/is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-portal-2-game-completion-background).

For another example, [search](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:207%20%5Bportal-2%5D%20%5Bspoiler%5D) for this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20529/are-there-multiple-endings-to-portal-2s-singleplayer-mode).

Is this expected behaviour? Or is this a minor bug?
I looked [on meta GSE](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/736/provide-a-markdown-extension-to-hide-text-anti-spoiler) and [meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers), but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behavior. [There's already a Meta request about addressing this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89552/can-we-please-remove-spoilered-text-from-the-summary). If you do not like this behavior, then please, show your support and upvote that request. ♪

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll go and show my support now :) I have no idea how I managed to miss that when I was searching to see if this had already been asked

Comment: Man, I went there all ready to upvote it and then I read the answers, with which I agree.