# Allow spoiler text to be inline with a surrounding paragraph

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

Spoiler text has already been basically implemented as shown in

> [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/736/provide-a-markdown-extension-to-hide-text-anti-spoiler)

post.. What I would like is to not have an entire spoiler block breaking up sentences and paragraphs, and instead have it appear inline, similar to how **bold** and *italics* are handled. In otherwords, making the following text between the square brackets `[]` only visible on mouse over:

> Spoiler text has already been basically implemented as shown in [this] post..

As another example, the question I wanted to put this into had this snippet of text in it (Note that if you keep on reading you will get a Skyrim spoiler)

*There is one house not far from the Gildegreen tree that's been boarded up at least since the Stormcloak invasion, and cannot be entered. Please tell me this isn't it?*

I would prefer to have the part about the stormcloak invasion blanked out at least, but using a spoiler block turns this one sentence into a lot of vertical scroll like:

*There is one house not far from the Gildegreen tree that's been boarded up*

> *at least since the Stormcloak invasion,*

*and cannot be entered. Please tell me this isn't it?*

Comment: So can I ask why the -1? Do I need to clarify the extension or is it just not a good idea?

Comment: I almost don't want this as I foresee people abusing this like on TVTropes where entire entries are blanked except for random articles and conjunctions.

Comment: Even from reading the original post about this it does not have wide SE use. I just feel it is fairly useful for gaming however. Gaming is one of those weird things where you generally want a very specific question asked/answered with out the entire situation explained openly, depending on who you are. @NickT Isnt that where those of us who can come through and edit the posts to provide some level of quality come in?

Answer (score 7):

I don't like this idea; the current spoiler tag forces people to condense their spoilery thoughts into sections.  I hate entries on TVTropes that look like this:

[image: TVTropes spoiler style]

(Their tag requires you highlight the text to reveal.)  Some of the editors there go *nuts* with the tag and make unreadable pages which I think stems from being unable (not trying hard enough) to compartmentalize a spoiler into a tight little bundle.

I don't really equate the baby with the bathwater, but I think there needs to be more of *a demonstrated need* before implementing something like this.

That said, as far as use on other sites is concerned, SciFi and Movies could also (mis)use such a thing at the very least.

Comment: I certainly do not want to promote this site starting to look like the above example from TVTropes.. I do however not see how you could separate what is clearly vital information from the Skyrim example I added to the original question with out just removing all of it from the question. Maybe the solution is to simply not include the extra information? I guess there may be a thin line between extra information to get a better answer and enough information to get the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the mighty powers of rephrasing!

> *There is one house not far from the Gildegreen tree that's been boarded up and cannot be entered.*
>
> > It's been boarded up at least since the Stormcloak invasion.
>
> Please tell me this isn't it?

The potential for abuse is simply too high. Just look at people abusing `backticks` for quoting, emphasis <kbd>and other <kbd>evil, <kbd>chaotic</kbd> evil</kbd> purposes</kbd>.

Comment: [abuse? what are you talking about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974/146482)? :-P